# Where Can I get good certification as server admin?

Tags: networking, security

I programmer without job.
Where Can I get good security network certification (online ) as server admin, that will help me to get better Job?

Thanks

Comment: Come on with the close already .. this could be interesting. Kind of interesting that "High Maintenance User" squillman and "Best sysadmin podcast" Zoredache" voted to close as "subjective".

Comment: @tomjedrz, I just noticed your comment.  I wish the system would notify if my name was used anywhere. Anyway, both those example questions where marked as community wiki.  Plus there are already several questions about career-development that seem to cover the similar information.  I  don't have an objection to the content of the question, just how it is was written/asked.  You could have edited and and cast a voted to reopen.

Comment: @zoredache .. Sorry if I offended you; that wasn't my intent. I find the whole "close" thing (other than dup and wrong site) kind of silly. It brings up just this kind of inanity. What is subjective or inappropriate to you seems great discussion to me, and it only takes 5 to close. This question is at least as objective and on-topic as "best sysadmin podcast."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well... I'm currently working as a sysadmin, and, even I haven't studied to be a sysadmin, what I've done is to practice a lot...

I currently maintain a server with my home computer, which I personally installed, configured and I usually play around with it (learning a lot in the process).

It may be a slow procedure, but I was working as a programmer, and 2 years later (since I started playing with my home computer as a server), I got this great job that now I'm at...

The thing is, you may not have the possibility to study at school, but you can learn for your own, there's the internet, and your own capabilities to get it done, it's just a matter of really wanting (and liking) it

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're not asking for websites that would try to get you certifications without education, because then you would (or should) stay unemployed.

However, if you're looking for education, which will give you skills as well as the potential to earn certifications, New Horizons is all over the US. Since you didn't specify your location, and I'm in the US, I can only give you an answer based on my experience. They also have online classes, but if you're very unfamiliar with something technical, actual classes can be preferable. Many people have different learning styles - again, I'm answering from my own experience.

Cisco also has Cisco Academy, which can get you education and certification in networks and get you started on security. I don't know if that's a US-only program; I know they do it with community and technical colleges here.

Also - what are you looking for? You say "security" and "network", and then say "server admin." Do you want to be a jack-of-all-trades and do it all? There's kind of two paths there with overlap: either a consultant or small-medium business IT guy.

You can also do it the hard way - utilize your existing skills to get into a company and learn on-the-job. That's how I did it - I earned my A+ on my own, got an SMB support job, and then got a job with a consulting firm that exposed me to a lot of growth opportunities.

Comment: Thank you very much, I not from US because that I need online.
Of course the best  way is study in Job like you say, but i cant get Job.I know basic admin, what I really dont know is security of server, network or just simple computer. I looking really job as Software Web development - (I educated in University), and I try more education as possible to get the Job.